# I keep getting an error: "TypeError: countries.map is not a function"

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting

> TypeError: countries.map is not a function

and I cannot figure out why. When I use comment out the `<Table />` and use `console.log(tableData)`, it shows up with the correct array of countries, however when I include the `<Table />` I do not get the arrays.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Select,
  Card,
  CardContent
} from "@material-ui/core";
import InfoBox from "./InfoBox";
import Map from "./Map";
import './App.css';
import Table from "./Table";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(["worldwide"]);
  const [countryInfo, setCountryInfo] = useState({});
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountryInfo(data);
      })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = async () => {
      await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const countries = data.map((country) => (
            {
              name: country.country,
              value: country.countryInfo.iso2
            }
          ));

        setTableData(data);
        setCountries(countries);
      });
    };

    getCountriesData();
  }, []);

  const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;

    const url = countryCode === 'worldwide' ? 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all' : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`;

    await fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCountry(countryCode);

        //All data from country
        setCountryInfo(data);
      })
  };

  console.log('COUNTRY INFO >>>', countryInfo);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__left">
        <div className="app__header">
        <h1>COVID-19 STATS</h1>
          <FormControl className="app__dropdown">
            <Select variant="outlined" onChange={onCountryChange} value={country}>
              <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
              {
                countries.map((country) => (
                  <MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>
                ))
              }
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>

        <div className="app__stats">
          <InfoBox title="COVID-19 Cases" cases={countryInfo.todayCases} total={countryInfo.cases} />

          <InfoBox title="Recovered" cases={countryInfo.todayRecovered} total={countryInfo.recovered}/>

          <InfoBox title="Deaths" cases={countryInfo.todayDeaths} total={countryInfo.deaths} />
        </div>

        <Map />
      </div>
      <Card className="app__right">
        <CardContent>
          <h3>Live cases per country</h3>
          {console.log(tableData)}
          <Table countries={tableData} />
          <h3>Worldwide new cases</h3>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Table.js file:

```
import React from 'react'

function Table({ countries }) {
    return <div className="table">
        {countries.map(({ country, cases }) => (
            <tr>
                <td>{country}</td>
                <td>{cases}</td>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </div>
}

export default Table
```

Comment: Looks like your API (https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all) is returning an object and not an array

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it only matter what disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries returns? As far as I can tell the disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all isn't connected to the table, which is what is causing the error.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, I mixed up your two states (probably because you add it as a countries prop in the table component), looks like [brijesh-pant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067188/5648954) might have the answer

Comment: Yep that was it. When I was logging it I guess I didn't realize it was an array inside of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({});`, you're setting `tableData` as an object.
Also, the API results with data which is an object and is `tableData` is set as an object again
`setTableData(data);`

When using `<Table countries={tableData} />` component `tableData` is an object and not an array.

Comment: Good eye! To be clear for OP, all you need to do is change `useState({})` in the `tableData` line to `useState([])`. Works in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-curran-pvmyn

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple... I appreciate it man!

Answer (score 1):

```
Check the sort function used you must have returned something wrong
export const sortData = (data) => {
  const sortedData = [...data]; //copy the data to sortedData
  sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.cases > b.cases) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });
  return sortedData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add check if countries exists.

```
countries && countries.map(({ country, cases }) => {}
```